# How to insert form fields in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am new to php codeigniter, Please any one tell me how to insert form fields in mysql using codeigniter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please add some code that you have tried

Comment: [CODEIGNITER FORM HELPER DOCUMENTATION](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, study the codeigniter Active Record, you will find all the ways to insert data into the database, including your form fields as well. It is available on codeigniters website as well, codeigniter is a well documented php framework, so you will find lots of help out there.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Here you will find all the guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

Comment: Could you specify a bit more about your answer? It's generally a good practice to provide some explanations with the answers you post.

Answer (score 0):

controller

```
 $data = array(
'title' => 'My title' ,
'name' => 'My Name' ,
'date' => 'My date' 
);
 $this->modelname->form_insert($data);
```

model

```
function form_insert($data){
$this->db->insert('tablename', $data);}
```

view

```
<?php echo form_label(' Name :'); ?> 
<?php echo form_error('Name'); ?>
<?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'id', 'name' =>'Name')); ?>
```